# Why My Database Column List Returning Unit

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

ı am trying to use a method which is getValues(). Im trying to take all my value variable from my SQL table and trying to make an addition with them. At the end, ı am trying to print my "value list" but it is just returning "Unit". The result that ı'm trying to reach: sum them all and get the total result.

```
var incomeList: List<Int> = mIncomeViewModel.getValues() // it is automaticly corrects me as incomeList: Unit
```

```
@Dao
interface IncomeDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addIncome(income: Income)

    @Update
    suspend fun updateIncome(income: Income)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteIncome(income: Income)

    @Query("DELETE FROM income_table")
    suspend fun deleteAllIncomes()

    @Query("SELECT * FROM income_table ORDER BY id ASC")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<List<Income>>

    @Query("SELECT value FROM income_table ")
    fun getValues(): LiveData<List<Int>>
}



class IncomeRepository (private val incomeDao: IncomeDao) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<Income>> = incomeDao.readAllData()

    suspend fun addIncome(income: Income){
        incomeDao.addIncome(income)
    }

    suspend fun updateIncome(income: Income){
        incomeDao.updateIncome(income)
    }

    suspend fun deleteIncome(income: Income){
        incomeDao.deleteIncome(income)
    }

    suspend fun deleteAllIncomes(){
        incomeDao.deleteAllIncomes()
    }

     fun getValues(): LiveData<List<Int>> {
        return incomeDao.getValues()
    }


}


class IncomeViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val readAllData: LiveData<List<Income>> //if anything happens by the private of this variable make it public again
    private val repository: IncomeRepository

    init {
        val incomeDao = IncomeDatabase.getDatabase(application).incomeDao()
        repository = IncomeRepository(incomeDao)
        readAllData = repository.readAllData
    }

    fun addIncome(income: Income){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.addIncome(income)
        }
    }

    fun updateIncome(income: Income){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            repository.updateIncome(income)
        }
    }

    fun deleteIncome(income: Income){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.deleteIncome(income)
        }
    }

    fun deleteAllIncomes(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.deleteAllIncomes()
        }
    }

    fun getValues(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            repository.getValues()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I fixed my problem with returning the ViewModel methods as LiveData<List>

```
fun getValues(): LiveData<List<Int>>{
        return repository.getValues()
    }
```